# Spring Kafka - Consume last N messages for partitions(s) for any topic

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm trying to read the requested no of kafka messages.
For non transactional messages we would seek from endoffset - N for M partitions start polling and collect messages where current offset is less than end offset for each partitions. For idempotent/transactional messages we have to account for transaction markers/duplicate messages and meaning offsets will not be continuous, in such case endoffset - N will not return N messages and we would need go back and seek for more messages until we have N messages for each partitions or beginning offset is reached

As there are multiple partitions I would need to keep track of all the offsets read so I can stop when all is done. There are two steps, first step to calculate the the start offset (end offset - requested no of messages) and end offset. ( the offsets are not continuous there are gaps) and I would seek the partition to start consuming from start offset. Second step is to poll the messages and count the messages in each partitions and if we don't meet the requested no of messages repeat first and second step again until we met the no of messages for each partition.

Conditions

Initial poll may not return any records so continue polling. 
Stop polling when you have reached the end offset for each partition or poll returns no results. 
Check each partition for messages read same as messages requested. If yes mark as complete, if no mark as continue and repeat steps. Account for gaps in messages.
Should work for both transactional and non transactional producer.

Question:

How would I go about keeping track of all the messages have been read for each partition and break out of loop ? Messages in each partition will come in order if it is helpful.

Does spring kafka support such use case ? More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58276749/2683814)

**Update**: I'm asking to read last N messages in each partition. Partitions and no of messages is the user input. I would like to keep all the offset management in the memory. In essence we are trying to read the messages in the LIFO order. This makes it tricky as Kafka allows you to read forward not backward.

Comment: Your requirements are not really clear. If you create a single consumer in a group of its own, partitioning doesn't apply... Or is it relevant to the info you seek? Otherwise I'd just poll and fill a list until a timeout occurs and the list contains the requested number of elements.

Comment: Sorry, added update. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Are you only reading unread messages?

Comment: You say "user input" so this doesn't involve polling?

Comment: Could you maybe add a method signature so it's clear what you expect as input and output? It sounds to me like `public Map<Integer, List<Message>> poll(List<Integer> partitions, int messageCountPerPartition`), and it should only return when each of the lists in the map have the expected message count and no further messages are available?

Comment: @daniu Method signature is correct.

Comment: @George I’m trying to read existing messages. This operation will be performed on user request. I’ve added more details in the comment to the answer.

Comment: @SagarVeeram what did you end up with? In my oppinion the requirements are clear. I was looking for a method to consume messages in reverse order, but I think that's not supported.

Comment: @kentor It is not supported out of the box. I end up creating a iterator wrapping poll results,  tracking offsets/partition and aggregating the results and seek next previous messages until requested no of count is met.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there such a need, I don't understand. Kafka itself manages when there is nothing in the queue. If messages jump from state-to-state, one can have separate queues/topics. However, here's how one can do it.

When we consume messages from a partition using something like -

```
ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = something; //initialize consumer
while (it.hasNext()) {
  MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> messageAndMetadata = it.next();
  String kafkaMessage = new String(messageAndMetadata.message());
  int partition = messageAndMetadata.partition();
  long offset = messageAndMetadata.offset();
  boolean processed = false;
  do{
    long maxOffset = something; //fetch from db
    //if offset<maxOffset, then process messages and manual commit
    //else busy wait or something more useful
  }while(processed);
}
```

We get information about about the offsets, partition number and the message itself. You can choose to do anything with this info.

For your use-case, you might also decide to persist the consumed offsets into a database so that the next time, offsets can be adjusted. Also, I would recommend shutdown hookup for cleanup and a final saving the processed offsets to DB.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, this should be doable with a standard Kafka `Consumer`.

```
Consumer<?, Message> consumer = ...

public Map<Integer, List<Message>> readLatestFromPartitions(String topic, Collection<Integer> partitions, int count) {

    // create the TopicPartitions we want to read
    List<TopicPartition> tps = partitions.stream().map(p -> new TopicPartition(topic, p)).collect(toList());
    consumer.assign(tps);

    // create and initialize the result map
    Map<Integer, List<Message>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Integer i : partitions) { result.add(new ArrayList<>()); }

    // read until the expected count has been read for all partitions
    while (result.valueSet().stream().findAny(l -> l.size() < count)) {
        // read until the end of the topic
        ConsumerRecords<?, Message> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        while (records.count() > 0) {
            Iterator<ConsumerRecord<?, Message>> recordIterator = records.iterator();
            while (recordIterator.hasNext()) {
                ConsumerRecord<?, Message> record = recordIterator.next();
                List<Message> addTo = result.get(record.partition);
                // only allow 10 entries per partition
                if (addTo.size() >= count) {
                    addTo.remove(0);
                }
                addTo.add(record.value);
            }
            records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        }
        // now we have read the whole topic for the given partitions.
        // if all lists contain the expected count, the loop will finish;
        // otherwise it will wait for more data to arrive.
    }

    // the map now contains the messages in the order they were sent,
    // we want them reversed (LIFO)
    Map<Integer, List<Message>> returnValue = new HashMap<>();
    result.forEach((k, v) -> returnValue.put(k, Collections.reverse(v)));
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @daniu. I’m trying to read already existing messages on the topic from the moment.Our use case is  user requests N messages on M portion for X topic then I should be able to go back N messages from the end offset for each of M topic partitions.

Comment: For non transactional messages we would seek from endoffset - N for M partitions start polling and collect messages where current offset is less than end offset for each partitions. For idempotent/transactional messages we have to account for transaction markers/duplicate messages and meaning offsets will not be continuous, in such case endoffset - N will not return N messages and we would need go back and seek for more messages until we have N messages for each partitions or beginning offset is reached.